# Can a REST API returns properties values that does not exists on database?

Tags: json, rest, api

Imagine that I have on my DB one table called 'match' and I store:

- id
- round_id
- score
- start_date
- end_date

When my REST API returns an JSON on endpoint /matches i must obligatorily return only the fields/columns that exists in the DB or I can return some custom fields like this:

```
{id: 1, is_over: true, no_goals: false}
```

Also, this table `match` has only relationship with the `round` table, and the `round` table has an relationship with `season` that has relationship with the `competition` table.

In the /matchs endpoints json, can I return `competition` data direclty ? Something like this:

/matchs:

```
{id: 1, is_over: true, no_goals: false, competition: { id: 2, name: 'foo',...}}
```

Comment: How would anyone even know that you're returning fields that aren't in your database?

Answer (score 1):

It's your API. You can do whatever you want with it!

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a REST API, you work with data.
In this case, you still work with data, you just add new fields which are not in you database. 
So it's possible, it's OK to do so, you don't break the REST API model. One thing a lot of people do is to inject new field about your request, like a custom http code, or a custom message.

And for competition, you can do it this way

So all good !

Comment: Thank you @sheplu! And any light about how to return an deep parent relationship based on REST model? I know that an simple parente/child relationship I should use _expand/_embed on my API query params. But those deeps relationships, that dont have an FK direclty I have no idea.

Comment: fully depends on how you implement your API. Could be just a param in your URL or body request. There is no 'best practice' on how to do it.  
But if you always send back your competition's data, you don't need to specify in your URL you want this, because you will always send them